Can't exit Stopmode using Threadx and NetxDuo on STM32 microcontroller
I'm working on a project where we have to program an STM32 board to enter stop mode and only wake up when an Ethernet packet is received (wake-on-lan function). I started by installing the ThreadX OS with NetX Duo and simply enabling stop mode, but it doesn't wake up! I programmed the user button to generate EXTI interrupts, but nothing happens. I tried this same strategy without NetX Duo, and it seems to work fine.

used borad: NUCLEO - H563ZI

this is what i do to start StopMode (this code is the NetxDuo thread function):
static VOID nx_app_thread_entry (ULONG thread_input)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Nx_App_Thread_Entry 0 */

    HAL_SuspendTick();
    HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);

  /* USER CODE END Nx_App_Thread_Entry 0 */

}

and this is how i setup the controller:
controller setup
I tried what's shown in the figure, i was expecting the execution to continue after pressing the button. If it worked i would have start to work on the Ethernet wake up.
if more information are needed i will provide them as soon as i can.
